# Patch glyph not updated when using multiple ColumnDataSources in bokeh app

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to use the bokeh server to plot a time series together with a shaded percentile band around, and this, since bokeh does not support the fill_between function from matplotlib, requires the construction of a patch object of double dimension. Hence, I need two `ColumnDataSources` to hold the data. However, only the first curve is rendered correctly when the data changes. Although the `data_source` of the `GlyphRenderer` is updated, the figure does not change. I use bokeh 0.12.3, and have tried with several servers and browsers. A complete, and reasonably minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select


class AppData:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.p_source = None
        self.c_source = None
        self.x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
        self.n = n
        self.ys = [np.sin(self.x) - i for i in range(self.n)]
        self.line = None
        self.patch = None

    def update_module(self, a, b):
        assert b - a == 5

        p_data = dict() if self.p_source is None else self.p_source.data
        c_data = dict() if self.c_source is None else self.c_source.data

        ys = [self.ys[j] for j in range(a, b)]
        if "x" not in c_data:
            c_data["x"] = self.x
            p_data["x"] = c_data["x"].tolist() + c_data["x"][::-1].tolist()

        n_r = len(ys[0])
        n_p = 2*n_r
        if "ys" not in p_data:
            p_data["ys"] = np.empty((n_p))

        p_data["ys"][:n_r] = ys[0]
        p_data["ys"][n_r:] = np.flipud(ys[-1])
        c_data["y"] = ys[2]
        if self.p_source is None:
            self.p_source = ColumnDataSource(data=p_data)
        else:
            self.p_source.data.update(p_data)
        if self.c_source is None:
            self.c_source = ColumnDataSource(data=c_data)
        else:
            self.c_source.data.update(c_data)
        if self.line is not None:
            print(max(self.line.data_source.data["y"]))
            print(max(self.patch.data_source.data["ys"]))  # The value changes, but the figure does not!

# initialize
app_data = AppData(10)
app_data.update_module(4, 4 + 5)
s1 = figure(width=500, plot_height=125, title=None, toolbar_location="above")
app_data.line = s1.line("x", "y", source=app_data.c_source)
app_data.patch = s1.patch("x", "ys", source=app_data.p_source, alpha=0.3, line_width=0)

select = Select(title="Case", options=[str(i) for i in range(5)], value="4")
def select_case(attrname, old, new):
    a = int(select.value)
    app_data.update_module(a, a + 5)

select.on_change('value', select_case)
layout = column(select, s1)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "Example of patches not being updated"
```

I am certainly not very experienced in using bokeh, so I could very well be using the system wrong. However, any help on this matter would be of great help!

Comment: One immediate observation: both `xs` ***and*** `ys` properties for `patches` have to be "lists of lists", and the shapes of all the sublists have to match up. You are creating a list of lists for `ys` but you are passing in `x` which is just a 1d numpy array. Put another way: every single y coordinate in `ys` needs to have a corresponding x coordinate, and that is not the case in your code.

Comment: True for `patches` but not for `patch`, see  http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it :) I didn't notice you were using `patch` it's pretty rarely used AFAIK. But in that case my comment is just the converse: *none* of the properties for `patch` should be "lists of lists" (as `ys` is)

Comment: Could the problem be I'm using numpy arrays and not lists as xs and ys?

Comment: No, the problem (or at least one problem) is that `x` is a 1d array like `array([1,2,3,4])` and `ys` is a list of arrays like `[array(...), array(...), ...]` The x and y coordinate list/array/sequences/whatever need to have *exactly the same shape*. Or maybe do you mean to be calling `s1.patch("x", "y")` instead of `s1.patch("x", "ys")` ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, both structures are arrays of equal lengths, two times the length of the initial curve. For the patch I first lay out the x/y pairs of the upper curve, and then the reverse pairs of the second curve, completing the patch. The figure renders fine, but the patch does not update later.

Comment: Just to complete my comment, `s1.patch("x", "ys", source=app_data.p_source)`, where the `"x"` in `app_data.p_source` is given by the expression `p_data["x"] = c_data["x"].tolist() + c_data["x"][::-1].tolist()` has length `2*len(np.linspace(0, 10, 20))` which is the same as the length of `app_data.source["ys"]`, which is a 1d `numpy.array`..

Comment: I got my example to work by always allocating new memory for the entries in the data_source dictionaries, i.e. by removing the conditionals for allocating `x`s, `y`, and `ys` only the first time the `update_module` method is called. Is there a flag I can use for the glyph renderer to tell it that the data has changed? Something a-la `has_changed(True)`?

Comment: I can't really visualize the changes you describe, maybe you can post complete code (perhaps in a new question)

Comment: I'll do that, thx!

Comment: @Ola Did you post your complete code anywhere? I am trying to make an interactive app where in each figure, I need to have two glyphs with data from different ColumnDataSources. I cannot make it work. Do you know how to do that?